# How to write proper tests for Y.io

Tags: javascript, testing, tdd, yui, yui3

I'm currently trying to write an application using YUI3 and via the TDD methodology.  I'm running into an issue where I can't figure out how to properly write tests to test the code that leverages [YUI3 `Y.io`.](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/)

According to the [`YUITest` docs](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/test/#mockobjects), they talk about Mock Objects and the `XMLRequestObject.`  Which is essentially what I'm trying to Mock out.  But I can't figure out how to do it when I'm using `Y.io` instead of `XMLRequestObject`.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Can you give more details on the type of tests you want to run? Depending on the type of `Y.io` tests you want to run, it might be better to use [echoecho](https://github.com/davglass/echoecho) to run them.  We use this inside of our own `Y.io` tests within YUI as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell `Y.IO` to use a custom transport other than the default `XMLRequestObject`. There may be other ways to add custom transports to `Y.IO`, but this worked for me:

Create a function that monkey patches a custom transport mode, *mock*, to `Y.IO`:

```
function _createMockTransport(mockXHR) {
    Y.IO.transports.mock = function () {
        return mockXHR;
    }
}
```

Then, in your setup function, add a variant of the following:

```
// I change the Y.IO instantiation configuration when instantiating my application
this.application = new Application({ yIOConfig: { xdr: { use: 'mock' }}})

this.xhr = Y.Mock();
Y.Mock.expect(this.xhr, {
    method: 'send',
    args: [Y.Mock.Value.Object, '/foo', Y.Mock.Value.Object]
});

_createMockTransport(this.xhr);
```

A example test would look like this:

```
"test /foo": function () {
    this.appliation.doServerCall();
    Y.Mock.verify(this.xhr);
},
```